# how to strisplit a vecter on a dot position reversely in r

Tags: r

I have a vector:

```
v <- c("1.1",   "10.10",   "11.11",   "12.12", "13.1.13", "13.2.13",   "14.14")
```

I would like to eliminate the behind part of the reverse first dot.
so my expected result is

```
c("1", "10", "11", "12", "13.1", "13.2", "14")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sub` to do this by matching the `.` (as `.` is a metacharacter specifying for any character element, we need to escape (`\\`) it to get the literal `.`) followed by one or more (`+`) elements that are not a dot (`[^.]+`) till the end of (`$`) the string and replace it with `""`.

```
sub("\\.[^.]+$", "", v)
#[1] "1"    "10"   "11"   "12"   "13.1" "13.2" "14"
```

Comment: I love the clarity you use to put in prose the regex... Thanks for inspiring so many!